# How to create a function to change a value in a 2D dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, dimensional

I've been tasked with creating a class for a two dimensional dynamic array and I am stuck at a part where I need to create a member function which I can call upon to change a specific position in the 2D array to a value of my choosing.

```
class TwoD
{
public:
    void setRowCol(int numRow, int numCol, double value);
    TwoD();
    TwoD(int row, int col);
    void fillArray();
    void outputArray();



private:
    double** dArray = new double* [MaxRow];
    int MaxRow;
    int MaxCol;


};



TwoD::TwoD()
{
    MaxCol = 3;
    MaxRow = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {

        dArray[i] = new double[3];

    }

}

void TwoD::setRowCol(int numRow, int numCol, double value)
{
    dArray[numRow][numCol] = value;

}
```

So the part I am having trouble with is the last part with the function setRowCol. I think that the problem is that it's not passing a 'deep' copy of the array but rather the original array itself.

Comment: no. how is it behaving?

Comment: because I don't see how this compiles or functions if you try to allocate the first array before the size has been set.

Comment: What happens is that the array doesn't change at all. It stays the same.

Comment: Simpler to use `std::vector` (to respect freely rule of 0/3/5).

Comment: I am not allowed to use vectors for this question since the course doesn't cover them. Funny how every problem I have everyone says it would be easier to use vectors, I wonder why they don't teach them.

Answer (score 0):

Make the MaxRow as static variable & initialize it to appropriate value(3) before using it to create dArray.

Comment: What if I want the user to define the size using the parametrized constructor?

Comment: Then u need to create the dArray at constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Without `std::vector`, and using `double**`, you may have something like:

```
class TwoD
{
public:
    TwoD(int row, int col) : maxRow(row), maxCol(col) {
        dArray = new double* [maxRow];
        for (int i = 0; i != maxRow; ++i) {
            dArray[i] = new double[maxCol] {};
        }
    }

    ~TwoD() {
        Delete();
    }

    TwoD(const TwoD& rhs) : maxRow(rhs.maxRow), maxCol(rhs.maxCol) {
        dArray = new double* [maxRow];
        for (int i = 0; i != maxRow; ++i) {
            dArray[i] = new double[maxCol];
            for (int j = 0; j != maxCol; ++j) {
                dArray[i][j] = rhs.dArray[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    TwoD& operator = (const TwoD& rhs) {
        if (&rhs == this) {
            return *this;
        }
        Delete();
        maxRow = rhs.maxRow;
        maxCol = rhs.maxCol;
        dArray = new double* [maxRow];
        for (int i = 0; i != maxRow; ++i) {
            dArray[i] = new double[maxCol];
            for (int j = 0; j != maxCol; ++j) {
                dArray[i][j] = rhs.dArray[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    void setRowCol(int numRow, int numCol, double value) {
        dArray[numRow][numCol] = value;
    }

private:
    void Delete() {
        for (int i = 0; i != maxRow; ++i) {
            delete [] dArray[i];
        }
        delete [] dArray;
    }

private:
    double** dArray;
    int maxRow;
    int maxCol;
};
```